# Selenium Java multithreading FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run parallel test and i have code something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
new Thread(()->{
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//fill profile
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); <- problem here
//all my actions
driver.close();
}).start();
}
```

But the problem is that the drivers are not created and not open multiple browsers instantly as ChromeDriver , and work consistently. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use testng it will provide feature to run test in parallel you don't need to create multi threading concept.[TestNg](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running)

Can also check below post:

[Using multithreading](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2015/01/road-to-parallel-execution-of-selenium_11.html)

[Using Testng](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2015/01/road-to-parallel-execution-of-selenium.html)

Comment: But how to do it using multithreading? In my example, if size = 20, 20 firefox drivers loaded sequentially two minutes, while the 20 Chrome drivers is loaded instantly.

Comment: 20 of any driver, on a single machine, is way too much.